# jquery fix scrolling on content part (mobile)

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

What I mean from my title is when I scroll on the aside part the content part scroll also !

So what I want to do is to fix position on content part when I scroll on the aside part !

These's my html structure

```
<div data-role="page" id="home" > 
    <div class="container"> 

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <aside class="sidemenu-container" >
            <div class="sidemenu">
            </div>
        </aside>
        <!-- =Sidebar -->

        <section class="content-container dark">

            <!-- Header -->
            <header class="header">
            </header>
            <!-- =Header -->

            <div class="content blog">
            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- =Main Content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it contains Jquery Mobile

Comment: I added the [tag:jquery-mobile] tag to your question. That should help more people who are familiar with the library find your question.

Comment: We still need to see your CSS for sidemenu, content etc as these are not part of the standard jQM CSS. Even better, can you create a jsFiddle that reproduces the issue?